# How do I get a citrix client receiver version number in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, citrix

I'm running a c#.NET application as a login/logout script on a XenApp server.  The application will run in a user context and I need to be able to retrieve the (client's) citrix receiver version number as well as the client os and machine name.

I'm fairly new to Citrix APIs and they don't seem to have very good documentation--anyone out there know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the citrix receiver version number in the windows registry on the XenApp server:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Citrix\Ica\Session\{SESSION_NUMBER}\Connection
```

where {SESSION_NUMBER} can be found in

```
HKEY_USERS\{SID_NUMBER}\Software\Citrix\SessionSfr
```

as the only subkey in that key, and where {SID_NUMBER} is the SID of the user logged into the XenApp session.

Comment: Can confirm that it still works in 2020. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I spent the weekend writing a .NET wrapper around the Citrix CCM SDK and published the code on GitHub: [CcmSdk.Net](https://github.com/sherman89/CcmSdk.Net)

The project targets `.NET Standard 2.1` at the moment because I needed the new UTF-8 marshaling functionality that is not available in older versions. If .NET Framework support is required, you can simply copy the code to a .NET Framework 4.7+ project and use that build instead.

Citrix Workspace sepersedes Citrix Receiver, and I think the registry method mentioned here doesn't work to find out the client version of Citrix Workspace, but it was still very helpful for me because many of our clients are still using the old Citrix Receiver.